# Vertically centering Multiple line Text and :before image element

Tags: css, icons, vertical-alignment

I have an element with text and an image in *::before* as its icon.
The text could be 1 or 2 lines high. I want the image and text both vertically centered. I tried with

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
```

here: http://jsfiddle.net/omw8umkq/3/  .
but i doesn't work. Without the ::before element the text would be centered but the images breaks it.
What should i do?

Comment: you could do it without pseudo-elements, try that demo - http://jsfiddle.net/omw8umkq/4/

Comment: @Mary Melody. looks good. but what if the icons vary in size to use that value for the padding-left?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without pseudo-elements, just set the `background-position` and `padding-left` to `.textcenter`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/omw8umkq/5/)**

**CSS:**

```
.textcenter {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    /*background: #cc1;*/
    background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/30');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I could work with this solution (i can use sass to get the image size for the padding), BUT it fails when i use Sprites as image source. How can i make Sprites here to work?

Comment: @user2520818 sorry I don't know much about sprites but that may help - http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/03/27/css-spriting-tips/ **and** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites **and** http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ or you should ask a new question about it on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)